# Rails query works in console but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have been building a practice application for rails. It's an simple blog application with only articles model, and tagging system which is done using Postgresql Arrays. Everything is fine except, I couldn't get the pages for specific tags to working.

The Activerecord query to fetch the posts matching the given tags is working properly in rails console, but the same fails when tried with View. I have verified and the params are passing through, please help.. I don't receive any error messages, from what I could understand the rails passes the **ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Article** as a result of query to the view, but the view file fails to display it list by list...

Below are the relevant files,

*routes.rb*

```
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#tagview', as: :tag
```

*articles_controller.rb*

```
  def tagview
    @articles = Article.where("'params[:tag]' = ANY (tags)")
  end
```

*tagview.html.erb*

```
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= article.title %></td>
        <td><%= article.content %></td>
        <td><%= article.tags.join(" ") %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

The resulting page is just blank. whereas the above query works in Rails console.

Comment: Have check `@articles.count` on view page? What it prints?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by looking at your logfile (log/development.log) and compare the SQL queries generated by the console and the controller, see what the differences are. It might even be helpful to paste the actual SQL queries here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The problem

Your original code sends a literal `'params[:tag]'` string to the database, and it would have no idea what to do with it. The resulting query looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ('params[:tag]' = ANY (tags));
```

This only returns articles that has actually been tagged with the literal `"params[:tag]"` string.

#### The solution

I guess you intend for `params[:tag]` to be replaced with the actual tag value coming in from `params`. To do this, you'd need to do something like:

```
Article.where(['? = ANY (tags)', params[:tag]])
```

which is going to result in something like this being sent to the database (fx when `params[:tag]` is set to `"foo"`):

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ('foo' = ANY (tags));
```

which is much more likely to be what you want.

#### Further reading

If you want to read more about how to construct queries with Active Record, the [section about Conditions in the Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) is a good place to start.

You probably won't find anything in the official documentation that talks about using PostgreSQL arrays as that is not a general database feature, though.

Comment: Wow, this works as intended.. Thanks.. BTW, any sources that I could reference in future? I have gone through the official Activerecord query guides, but id doesn't helped much.

Comment: I have update my answer with some more details and links to relevant docs.

Comment: Arrays actually are part of standard SQL. ActiveRecord is pretty ignorant about SQL though.